# After update to 0.12 gradle plugin script fails

Tags: android, gradle

I have updated my gradle plugin to `0.12.+`.

But after that i have the error message

```
Error:A problem was found with the configuration of task ':processDebugResources'.
> File 'build\manifests\debug\debug\AndroidManifest.xml' specified for property 'manifestFile' does not exist.`
```

Its worked perfect for `0.10.+` But android studio requires minimum 12.

The build part of the script :

```
android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.processManifest.doLast {
        copy {
            //SET COPY PATHS
            try {
                from("${buildDir}/manifests") {
                    println "from: ${buildDir}/manifests"
                    include "${variant.dirName}/AndroidManifest.xml"
                    println "included: ${variant.dirName}/AndroidManifest.xml"
                }
            } catch (e) {
                println "error: " + e
            }

            into("${buildDir}/manifests/${variant.name}")
            println "into (neues Manifest): ${buildDir}/manifests/${variant.name}"

            //DEFINE VARS
            def brandVersion = variant.buildType.name
            def brandVersionString = brandVersion.toString()
            def gmaps_key = mapsapiprops['googleapiDebug']


            if (brandVersionString.contains("release")) {
                gmaps_key = mapsapiprops['googleapiRelease']                    
            }

            //REPLACE LINES IN MANIFEST
            filter {
                String line ->
                    line.replaceAll("<meta-data android:name=\"com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY\" android:value=\"\"/>",
                        "<meta-data android:name=\"com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY\" android:value=\"" + gmaps_key + "\"/>");                    
            }
        }
    }              

    //SET PATH TO NEW MANIFEST
    variant.processResources.manifestFile = file("${buildDir}/manifests/${variant.name}/${variant.name}/AndroidManifest.xml")
}
```

Appreciate for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download the 0.5.7 Android Studio. Worked.